# OpenCV: Unable to correctly read a single channel png image with 16 bit depth

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, png

I am trying to read  a png image with single channel and 16 bit depth . Subsequently I am finding the pixel values on a line:

```
//read the image data in the file "MyPic.JPG" and store it in 'img'
Mat img = imread("sir.png",  CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH); 

//Iterate through the line along which Intensity profile is required 
LineIterator it(img, Point(1,1), Point(20,20), 8);

vector<Vec3b> buf;   

for(int i=0; i<it.count; i++)
{
    buf.push_back( Vec3b(*it) );
    it++;
}
//print pixel value on the selected line
cerr << Mat(buf) << endl;
```

The printed values are always nos which are less than 255:

```
156, 156, 164; 153, 153, 152; 154, 154, 139; 179, 179, 180; 182, 182, 176; 2
208, 167; 144, 144, 163; 204, 204, 206; 180, 180, 187; 174, 174, 170; 150, 1
162; 154, 154, 170; 157, 157, 181; 181, 181, 159; 164, 164, 152; 130, 130, 1
166, 166, 181; 153, 153, 170; 153, 153, 176; 180, 180, 198]
```

This means it is actually reading this image as 8 bit instead of 16 bit.

I verified my image in MATLAB and I can see values which are valid for 16 bit , such as :

```
d=imread('sir.png');
buf = improfile( d, [1 20], [1 20] )
```

which gives output such as:

> 65535
>          40092
>          39321
>          39578
>          46003
>          46774
>          53456
>          37008
>          52428
>          46260
>          44718
>          38550
>          39578
>          40349
>          46517
>          42148
>          33410
>          42662
>          39321
>          39321

Why is my result in opencv differing than the actual? How do I correctly read the image so that it shows values in 16 bit?

**Update**

Based on Roger's answer I have updated my code like this:

```
LineIterator it(img, Point(1,1), Point(20,20), 8);
vector<ushort> buf;

for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++)
{
    buf.push_back(img.at<ushort>(it.pos()));
}

cerr << Mat(buf) << endl;
```

But now ALL my pixel values are coming 40092, which is wrong  as compared to MATLAB output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `Vec3b` to process the pixels, this is chopping it up int 8-bit chunks.

Use `Vec3s` instead of `Vec3b`. That will give you 16-bit pixels. This assumes that you have 3-channels of 16-bit rather than one channel of 16-bit grayscale (which is what I think you'll get from a PNG), in which case you would access via `at<ushort>(y,x)` for example.

```
LineIterator it(img, Point(1,1), Point(20,20), 8);

vector<ushort> buf;

for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, it++)
{
    buf.push_back(img.at<ushort>(it.pos()));
}
```

Comment: so what is the solution ?

Comment: actually the original image is a single channel 16 bit image , so Vec3S is not working

Comment: Could you please put the code snippet for what I use in place of vec3b onward. My image in single channel.

Comment: This gives 20 same values of  40092, while this is valid for 16 bit image, but is wrong if I compare with MATLAB output

Comment: Indeed 40092  is one of the values as you can see in the MATLAB output. But why all values are coming like that?

Comment: @user2799508 Sorry - writing this without testing, see edit in the `for` loop.